# Cannot read property of 'insert' of underfined mongoDB NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to incorporate mongoDB into my application, however when I try to add to a collection I get the error 'cannot read property of 'insert' undefined when trying to start the server with nodeJS.

I appreciate that this has been asked before, however when I have tried to rectify the error as per another question asked on here by writing the following code, however I get `var` is not defined;

`var accountCollection = var mongodb = mongodb.collection('account');`
`accountCollection.insert({username:"wendy3", password:"lilac3"});`

The relevant code for my server is below, I have looked at many guides online and nothing seems to solve my problem, so any help would be appreciated.

```
//create server, listening on port 3000
//when there is a request to port 3000 the server is notified
//depending on the request a specific action will be carried out
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
//create connection to MongoDB
var db = mongodb('localhost:27017/Game', ['account', 'progress']);
//insert into collection
db.account.insert({username:"wendy3", password:"lilac3"});


var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

var colors = require('colors/safe');
```

Comment: `var accountCollection = var mongodb = mongodb.collection('account');` won't work because you have to declare mongodb before assign it in this syntax. `var mongodb; var accountCollection = mongodb = mongodb.collection('account')` will work

Comment: Thank you - I will try this when I manage get it the server to connect to the database!

Answer (score 2):

Connection to a database is an asynchronous operation but you're trying to access it as if it was synchronous.

If you look at the [examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb#connecting-to-mongodb) for the package you're using, it shows that you must you use a callback function which gets called once the connection response is received:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL 
var url = 'localhost:27017/Game';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server 
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) return console.log('Error: ' + err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you - I think I understand now ( I am new to MongoDB so please forgive me)

I now have the following code; however I am receiving error `invalid schema, expected mongodb.` Have I maybe put `MongoClient` in place of `mongodb` somewhere? So I can see that it is trying to connect, however the callback is returning an error.

Code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

//connection url
var url = ('localhost:27017/Game', 'account', 'progress');

//use connect method to connect to server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
if (err) return console.log('Error: ' + err);
console.log('mongodb is connected to the server');
});
```